# Is it possible to start an external program from the target directory when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

When debugging I need to start an external program from the target directory of a build and am wondering if it can be accomplished using relative paths.

As a post-build event I have the following:

```
IF NOT "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Debug" GOTO End
:CopyExecutable
copy "$(SolutionDir)\Source\Lib\MyExecutable.exe" "$(TargetDir)"
:End
```

I need to run MyExecutable.exe when I am debugging so in the debug tab for the project properties I set "Start external program" to MyExecutable.exe but get a failure when running the debug. It seems I need to put the full path for this to work.

Is there a way to do this using relative paths?

Comment: For those who still have this problem; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774745/using-relative-path-for-start-external-program-in-vs-net-2010#comment37905907_4774745) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774745/using-relative-path-for-start-external-program-in-vs-net-2010#comment37905830_5261113) comment.

Answer (score 5):

The 'Start External Program' path is relative to your solution directory (in VS2005 anyway).  So you could just put:

```
Source\Lib\MyExecutable.exe
```

I see you asked this a while ago, but I just ran into the same problem, and this is how I solved it.

Comment: For me, I did this, and it worked fine. But then I re-opened the Solution on a different day, and now it says it cannot find the file. The setting is exactly the same as it was (Solution-relative, single sub-folder), and the file is there. Has anyone had this issue? No files, folders, or paths have been changed since (it's tracked by Git).

Comment: @Michael, As an update, I deleted the `.vs` sub-folder (in the Solution folder), and after re-opening the Solution it worked just fine. Perhaps Visual Studio had cached something incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

(_Disclaimer: all directions are based on VS08.  Things may be in different places in prior or future versions)

I get the feeling that your other program is *not* a post-build step you need to run before debugging, but rather a program that also needs to run (a server or something) aswell *while* you debug.

Use an empty C++ Make-File project (you can use other project types, but this one by default does no actual building, so I find it's the easiest), and alter its start-up properties (Project/Properties -> Debug) to run your other application.  Then, set your solution to start multiple projects (Solution/Properties -> Common Properties -> Startup Project).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like $(TargetDir)\..\Lib ?

Comment: It is not possible to use $(TargetDir) in the startup program path