# How to define a relative path for 'Start external program' in VS 2010 project?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I know that here there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334373/is-it-possible-to-start-an-external-program-from-the-target-directory-when-debugg) but I would like, if possible, to be able to define a **relative path** for `'Start External Program'` or any workaround that do not constrain me to add a complete new empty project to my solution.

I am using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010 environment developing WinForms apps.

Comment: Had the same issue and a similar post. [**Here's what I found out**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774745/using-relative-path-for-start-external-program-in-vs-net-2010).

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot use project macros like `$(SolutionDir)` or environment variables for "Start external program:", you can use [relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334373/is-it-possible-to-start-an-external-program-from-the-target-directory-when-debugg/1141459#1141459) as long as a path relative to the solution directory solves your problem.  I just tested VS2010 and a VB.NET WinForms project and set "Start external program:" to:

- `..\..\..\windows\system32\cmd.exe`

and then `Ctrl+F5` runs a command prompt.  Adjust the number of `..` elements to the folder depth of your project.

Comment: I tried but not matter how many ..\ I use, Visual Studio always throw an error: The external program cannot be found. Please enter a valid executable file. Consider that all my projects are in D: and probably relative paths starts from the path where you have Visual Studio installed. Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 in my case.

Comment: To find you what folder it is relative to, just put `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`, press `Ctrl+F5` and type `cd` to display the current directory.  It's not where VS2010 is installed but the "Build output path:".

Comment: @Drake: you asked for a relative path but a relative path to a file on a different drive doesn't make sense.  In my test the project and the windows folder were on the same drive.  You can copy `cmd.exe` to the root of the D: drive to perform an equivalent test.

Comment: @RickSladkey I did open CMD on debug and got the output path. In my output path I want to start an exe, but it still fails to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use project macros, such as $(ProjectDir) and define from there.

See
[this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx)

Comment: `$(SolutionDir)` might be what you want.

Comment: Click the '...' near the command field, and there should be a hand macros button displaying all the available macros and their paths.

Comment: Sorry, this is C++ Projects only, however relative paths DO work in C# and VB.Net start external program

Comment: Be aware however that they are relative to the Visual Studio install path, specifically to \Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Comment: I found that macros can be used, but need to be set manually in the `.csproj` XML file. After doing this, the relevant sections from `.csproj.user` file should be deleted, if any.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible. Maybe using environement variables likes %CD% but i'm not sure.

But, this settings is save into the csproj.user (or probably vbproj.user in your case), so each dev can have his own settings easily :).

Comment: It doesn't seems that this kind of settings are stored in vbproj.user.

Comment: I'm mean the starting path is store into the .user file, i'm pretty sure.